# How do pass a model from controller to Layout Page

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to pass a ModelData from an Accountcontroller to _Layout.cshtml.

When I call the data in Login_New.cshtml, it the data is passed well, but on _Layout.cshtml.
The page keeps redirected constantly. I think the problem is with
            @Html.Action("Layout", "Account")

> In Login_New, it worked well.

```
@model dynamic
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login_New", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @id = "form", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
...
<input type="hidden" id="hidPublicKeyModulus" value="@Model.MODULUS"/>
                <input type="hidden" id="hidPublicKeyExponent" value="@Model.EXPONENT"/>
...
```

> AccountController

```
public class ModelData
        {
            public string USERPSWD { get; set; }
            public string USERID { get; set; }
            public string MODULUS { get; set; }
            public string EXPONENT { get; set; }

        }
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Layout()
  {
            ModelData bindingData = GetModelDataWithRSA(Session);

            //var md = new ModelData { EmailCount = 4, NotificationCount = 2 };
            return PartialView(bindingData);
        }

public ModelData GetModelDataWithRSA(HttpSessionStateBase session)
            {
            ModelData model = new ModelData();

            // RSA Encryption & decryption
            RSAParameters privateKey;
            if (session["privateKey"] == null)
            {
                privateKey = RSA.Create().ExportParameters(true);
            }
            else
            {
                var rsap = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                rsap.FromXmlString(session["privateKey"].ToString());
                privateKey = rsap.ExportParameters(true);
            }
            // Create Prive Key, Public Key
            RSAParameters publicKey = new RSAParameters();
            publicKey.Modulus = privateKey.Modulus;
            publicKey.Exponent = privateKey.Exponent;

            String publicModulus = "";
            String publicExponent = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < privateKey.Modulus.Length; i++)
            {
                publicModulus += privateKey.Modulus[i].ToString("X2");
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < privateKey.Exponent.Length; i++)
            {
                publicExponent += privateKey.Exponent[i].ToString("X2");
            }

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(); 
            rsa.ImportParameters(privateKey);
            string privateKeyText = rsa.ToXmlString(true);


            model.EXPONENT = publicExponent;
            model.MODULUS = publicModulus;

            session["privateKey"] = privateKeyText;

            return model;
        }
```

> _Layout.cshtml

```
@model dynamic

<div>@Html.Action("Layout", "Account")</div>
                <input type="hidden" id="hidPublicKeyModulus" value="@Model.MODULUS" />
                <input type="hidden" id="hidPublicKeyExponent" value="@Model.EXPONENT" />
```

Comment: Use  @{Html.RenderAction("Layout", "Account")}, it will renders directly to response

Comment: Are you sure that _Layout.cshtml contains a model ?

Comment: What I need is _Layout.cshtml have a model from accountcontroller (or others).

Comment: I solved this problem by sending @Viewbag from AccountController to Layout!
Thank you for all who helped me :)